# android - admob implmetation confusion

Tags: android, eclipse, admob

I have implemented admob code as given in google site (http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html) as described  in google  site we should target android 3.2 (api-13) in eclipse IDE to work properly. now my problem is my application targeting the android version 1.6 and above, since i made build target as andoird 3.2 it expects  app should run on either 3.2 emulator or any of 3.2 device. i tried even installing on my 2.2 device but it didnt work.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by it didn't work, can't install, no ad shown or application crash with exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you need to do is follow their instruction:

> Requirements
>   The Google AdMob Ads SDK for Android requires Android 1.5 or later. Make sure you have the latest copy of the Android SDK and that you're compiling against at least Android v3.2 (set target in default.properties to android-13).

Using Android SDK Tool download android-13 SDK and modify your default.properties, do not change anything else like android:minSdkVersion in AndroidManifest.xml. Yes, you will get a little yellow warning message says version not match in Eclipse, just ignore it and build your application, you should be fine.

Comment: i followed the same instruction as given. and i don't understand to ignore the warning !? not sure where that will impact.

Comment: In short, it uses [Backward Compatibility & Reflection](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/backward-compatibility.html) ensure application built against later SDK can run on earlier Android system. minSdkVersion doesn't need to be greater equal than target SDK. just ignore the warning message.

Comment: Well the part I was missing is to download SKD-13 :) I had every one of them but this one accidently... thanks